# convert Javascript to Haxe using refactor

Tags: haxe, converters, haxelib

I want to convert a javascript class to Haxe. (Which is Nakama Backend [JS Client](https://github.com/heroiclabs/nakama-js/releases/tag/v2.0.1), nakama-js.umd.js)
in order to do that, I've tried to use [refactor](https://lib.haxe.org/p/refactor/) tool. which is a haxelib tool
after installing refactor, I've executed the following command:

```
haxelib run refactor js_to_haxe nakama-js.umd.js
```

but i get the following error:

```
Called from ? line 1
Called from Main.hx line 72
Called from hant/Process.hx line 196
Called from hant/Process.hx line 99
Called from a C function
Called from hant/Process.hx line 174
Called from hant/Process.hx line 173
Called from a C function
Called from C:\MyProg\_tools\motion-twin\haxe\std/neko/Lib.hx line 42
Uncaught exception - load.c(237) : Failed to load library : hant.ndll
Stack trace:
        Called from a C function
        Called from hant/Process.hx line 10
        Called from a C function
        Called from hant/Process.hx line 10
        Called from hant/Process.hx line 174
        Called from a C function
        Called from hant/Process.hx line 99
        Called from hant/Process.hx line 196
        Called from Main.hx line 72
        Called from ? line 1
```

I also tried installing hant lib. nothing changed.

Comment: I think you well have most luck by contacting the owner of the lib by creating an issue https://github.com/yar3333/haxe-refactor/issues

Answer (score 0):

```
$ haxelib run refactor convertFile input.js Output.hx js_to_haxe.rules
```

This seems to execute in haxe 4 (the invocation described in the docs was for 3.x).

The output doesn't really seem to transpile in Haxe though.